# Exercise on modules over PID involving injective modules, Baer's criterion. (Exercise IV.6.7 in Hungerford's Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

I'm interested if I solved this somewhat correctly, and would like to be set straight if it is wrong. This is an exercise from an introductory text.

**(Unless stated otherwise, all theorems and exercises are from Hungerford's *Algebra*.)**

> **Lemma IV.6.8:** Let $A$ be a module over a principal ideal domain $R$ such that $p^nA
>  = 0$ and $p^{n-1}A \neq 0$ for some prime $p \in R$. Let $a$ be an element of $A$ of order $p^n$. There is a submodule $C$ of $A$ such
> that $A = Ra \oplus C$.

Here order of $a$ is defined as the generator of the annihilator of cyclic submodule $Ra$.
The proof is given in elementary form, and additonally as an exercise involving injective modules and Baer's criterion:

> **Lemma IV.3.8:** Let $R$ be a unital ring. $R$-module $A$ is injective if and only if
> for every left ideal $L$ of $R$ and homomorphism $f$ of $L$ into $A$,
> $f$ extends to a homomorphism of $R$ into $A$.

One of the exercises made the criterion a bit easier to handle. Here is an equivalent statement:

> **Exercise IV.3.2:** Let $R$ be a unital ring. $R$-module $A$ is injective if and only if
> for every left ideal $L$ of $R$ and homomorphism $f$ of $L$ into $A$,
> there exists $a \in A$ such that $f(r) = ra$ for every $r \in L$.

And here is the sequence of exercises.

> **Exercise IV.6.7:** Let $A$ and $a \in A$ satisfy the hypotheses of Lemma IV.6.8.
>
> (i) Every $R$-submodule of $R/(p^n)$-module with action $(r+(p^n))a =
>  ra$. Conversely, every $R/(p^n)$-submodule of $A$ is an $R$-submodule
> by pullback along $R \rightarrow R/(p^n)$.
>
> (ii) The submodule $Ra$ is isomorphic to $R/(p^n)$.
>
> (iii) The only proper ideals of the ring $R/(p^n)$ are the ideals
> generated by $p^i + (p^n), (i= 1,2, \ldots , n-1)$
>
> (iv) $R/(p^n)$ is injective as $R/(p^n)$-module.
>
> (v) There exists $C$ such that $A = C \oplus Ra$.

(ii) $Ra \cong R/(p^n)$ by map $R \rightarrow Ra$ and Isomorphism theorems.

(iii) If $q \neq p$ is any prime in $R$ then $gcd(p,q) = gcd(p^n, q) = 1$ hence $xp^n + yq = 1$ so $q$ is invertible in $R/(p^n)$, hence the only nonunits in $R/(p^n)$ are $p^i (i=2,\ldots, n-1)$ and only these can generate proper (necessarily principal) ideals.

(iv) $L$ is any of the possible ideals of $R/(p^n)$ and $f:L \rightarrow R/(p^n)$ an $R/(p^n)$-module homomorphism. Image of $f$ is an $R/(p^n)$-submodule, so one of the ideals. Then since $L = \{cp^i + (p^n) \vert c \in R\}$, $f[cp^i + (p^n)] = (c+p^i)f[p^i+(p^n)]$, action of $f$ is determinated by where it sends $p^i + (p^n)$.

Let $f[p^i + (p^n)] = rp^j + (p^n)$ for some $r \in R$. If $j \geq i$ then $f[cp^i + (p^n)] = (c+(p^n))f[p^i+(p^n)] = crp^j + (p^n) = (cp^i + (p^n))(rp^{j-i} + (p^n))$. Hence the image of $L$ would be of the required form, and $R/(p^n)$ would be injective.

If $i > j$, then $0 + (p^n) = f[p^n + (p^n)] = (p^{n-i}+(p^n))f[p^i + (p^n)] = p^{n-i+j} + (p^n) \neq 0 + (p^n)$, contradiction.

(v) We have an exact sequence of $R/(p^n)$-modules $0 \rightarrow Ra \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/Ra \rightarrow 0$, where $Ra \cong R/(p^n)$ hence $Ra$ is injective and therefore the sequence splits, hence $A = Ra \oplus A/Ra$. These are $R$-modules again by pullback along canonical projection $R \rightarrow R/(p^n)$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks for reading it. I sort of thought it was too long for anybody to care enough to get through it. Indeed author leads the reader into a solution, but I need some confirmation I somewhat understood the material correctly, as similar concepts occur frequently later in the book.

Comment: @navigetor Exercise is from Hungerford. It is self-study, I complement it with Robert Ash's text Basic Abstract Algebra.

Comment: [Exercise is from Hungerford]---> is it "AbstractAlgebra An Introduction" ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Nope. They are from "Algebra" GTM 73.

Comment: I didn't read your (iii) because I think there is another better proof as follows. 

(i) follows immediately from Example (5) on page 338 in Dummit and Foote's _Abstract Algebra_.

(ii) follows immediately from Theorem IV.6.4.(iii).

(iii) See your proof.

(iv) I would set $a=f(1+\langle p^n\rangle)$. 

(v) follows immediately from Proposition IV.3.13.